How do fighter jets maintain control while wings are perpendicular to airflow direction?
In my understanding, a plane stays stable and "straight", largely because the control surfaces such as the tail fins keep it stable by applying force in the opposite direction of any unwanted drift.
However, I have seen fighter jets and even small RC aircraft, perform a maneuver to reduce speed, in which they rapidly pull up until they are vertical and flying perpendicular to airflow.  While this looks cool, my question is: how does the aircraft stay upright and stable during this maneuver?
What is preventing the aircraft from flipping to its side or beginning a spin?

I'll be mostly talking about high AOA lateral-directional static stability here. An important aerodynamic parameter to look for is the Cnβ dynamic, which provides a rough indication of the oscillation frequency of uncommanded roll-yaw motion, and whether a nose-slice type of yaw departure is possible at the current AOA.
The figure below shows such parameters typical of a spin-resistant twin-tailed swept-wing fighter, and how Cnβ dynamic is calculated.

Another example of the F-16A from NASA wind tunnel data:

Directional static stability derivative (Cnβ), or yawing moment coefficient (Cn) with regards to sideslip (β), shows which direction the aircraft would yaw if sideslip is present. A positive value means the aircraft tends to return to zero sideslip if unbalanced. Cnβ usually becomes negative at medium AOA ranges of 20-30 degrees, as the vertical tails are increasingly immersed in the wing/forebody wake.
Then there's the dihedral effect, or lateral static stability derivative (Clβ). It is the rolling moment coefficient (Cl) with regards to sideslip (β). A negative value means a positive dihedral effect, that the aircraft tends to roll into the yaw if sideslip is generated. This dihedral effect is also usually at its weakest at medium AOA ranges.
There's also asymmetric breakdown of the vortex flow at a medium AOA range of 30-50 deg, that can contribute to roll and yaw moment, so what you want to do is to pitch through those unstable AOA region as fast as possible, that the asymmetry in the flow pattern has little time to be formed.
Thus, an effective way for reducing lateral-directional disturbance at the post-stall regimes is to increase pitch rate and reduce the time staying in these AOAs full of separation phenomena and asymmetric flow patterns.
By reaching the high AOA range of 60-90 deg, the flows are fully separated and Cnβ dynamic tends to increase.
This is actually how a Cobra maneuver is possible with little roll-yaw motion by the Su-27. Note that I did not mention longitudinal stability here, but you can refer to this answer to see how such maneuver is aerodynamically possible in the pitch axis.

Good discussion. Differential horizontal tail deflections can create (or counter) some body axis yaw at higher angles of attack. Moments of inertia about the pitch axis (Iyy) and yaw axis (Izz) tend to be fairly high for aircraft demonstrating these maneuvers. I think another key point is as these air vehicles are transitioning to higher AoA's, it's important to keep roll and yaw rates small upon entry.

WRT "stay upright", it's a balance of moments about the pitch axis, including those created by aerodynamic forces, propulsion system forces, and inertia. Many configurations have horizontal tail designs which retain some effectiveness at high AoA. Thrust vectoring can make a big difference in pitch, especially at slower speeds/higher power settings.

@AeroAndy Very true. Differential horizontal tails are indeed very effective yaw devices at higher AOAs, making use of the adverse yaw created by asymmetric induced drag. It's so effective that non-TVC aircrafts such as F-18, F-35, as well as TVC aircraft such as F-22 (with 2D TVC of no yaw capability) actively deploys such control logic that increase yaw controllability at medium to high AOA.

Thank you for the informative response -- it was definitely very interesting.  But you didn't mention in the end, what design features affect the Cnβ?  What makes an aircraft perform better in this parameter?

@CaptainCodeman This would subject to the design of leading-edge flaps / slats, vortex generators, wing-fuselage and vertical tails. A wind tunnel is required to make such comparison by uninstalling a particular component and spot the differences in Cnβ and Clβ, but generally speaking, deploying leading-edge flaps / slats would positively affect Cnβ and Clβ in most AOA ranges. A higher aspect ratio and a larger area of vertical tail would positively affect Cnβ at lower AOA, but cannot guarantee an increase in Cnβ at high AOA. I would recommend a read of the paper NASA TN D-5361 for an example.

If you are talking about this:


how does the aircraft stay upright and stable during this maneuver?

It does not.  The aircraft is rotating.  You will not see an aircraft maintain this angle of attack for several minutes.  Typically it is closer to milliseconds.
Computer controlled aircraft do not need to be stable.



(The angle of attack in this video is less than 90 degrees.)
